# Admob Interstitial Ads not coming full screen on android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, admob, interstitial

I am implement Interstitial ads In my project but ads is not coming full screen

Here is my ads code :

```
this.interstitialAds = new InterstitialAd(this, "ca-app-pub-ID");
            this.interstitialAds.setAdListener(this);
            AdRequest adr = new AdRequest();
            // add your test device here
           adr.addTestDevice("8E452640BC83C672B070CDCA8AB9B06B");
            interstitialAds.loadAd(adr);
```

I am getting Ads like this

> [image]

And I want like this

> [image]

How I can set full screen ads ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is default behavior of admob ads, it solely depends on the advertiser to display his ad format. You cannot do anything in this. your ad is full screen you can check this by looking at the close button on top left of screen.